# How do homologous pairs find each other

Tags: molecular-genetics

If I'm not mistaken the only time homologous pairs of chromosomes need to find each other is during gamete formation in preparation for crossover recombination.
How do they find each other?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you might still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the time to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

I found [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10460409) from 1999.  From the abstract:

> It is concluded that DNA-DNA interactions cannot bridge the distances between homologous chromosomes in the nucleus, and it is suggested that protein chains are formed between homologous segments. These attach to homologous chains emanating from homologous sequences in other chromosomes, and the chains move along each other until the homologous DNA sequences meet.

For more recent publications, you can search the citing articles [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=459763864488789893&as_sdt=5,33&sciodt=0,33&hl=en).